# NSPredicate check all items in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I have an array of instances of my object - `MyObject`. Each instance has a string and an array property -  `myArrayProperty` which contains instances of another class - `MyOtherObject` I am using an `NSPredicate` to do some filtering based on the values in `myArrayProperty` as so:

```
  NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myArrayProperty.otherObjectProperty MATCHES %@", mySearchString];
```

In this case otherObject property is a string property of MyOtherObject. I suspect the problem is with this construct: `myArrayProperty.otherObjectPropert`

My question is, how do I instruct the predicate to go through all items in myArrayProperty? I would like to avoid using a for loop here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use...

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY myArrayProperty.otherObjectProperty MATCHES %@", mySearchString];
```

I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily check form nsobject or form some base class and easily do your tasks like:

```
ViewController *cont ;
NSMutableArray *array ;

[array addobject : cont];


nslog (@"%@",array);

for (UIViewController *crt in array ){
nslog (@"%@",crt);

}
```

like wise instead of UIViewcontroller use NSObject or other base class..